# ROW_NUMBER() without over in SQL

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

Is there any way to use `ROW_NUMBER()` in SQL without using `OVER`, because I want to use sorting.

I have a Grid with multiple sortable columns with configurable rows. In my scenario order by is variable that's why I am not able to put order by using ROWNUM.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have ROW_NUMBER. Why did you tag this with MySQL?

Comment: No [it is a mandatory part of the grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). Explain more about your root need for this rather than your proposed solution.

Comment: @MarkByers Sorry By Mistake, Removed !!

Comment: @MartinSmith , added more detail in question.

Comment: Still don't know what you need. Why do you need `ROW_NUMBER` at all? How does that fit into it? Supplying an example may make things clearer.

Comment: @MartinSmith let say I want to show 50 rows at a time and currently I am getting all the data from DB. I have a pagination which gives me no of records to show that's why I used ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @HaseebAkhtar - So you are using `ROW_NUMBER` to bring back records 51-100 say? How do you expect SQL Server to know what order you want without you defining it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [need to use ROW\_NUMBER without over in sqlserver 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914888/need-to-use-row-number-without-over-in-sqlserver-2005)

Answer (score 88):

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as number from Task order by RuleId
```

Comment: is this same as: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order By RuleId), I also do not want to repeat the same order by clause for OVER statement.

Comment: No, It is not the same, but produces the same results for this query. You can (SELECT NULL) instead real columns to skip ordering in 'window' in any (I think) complex scenarios with row_number()

Answer (score 0):

I approached this using a different logic. Instead of checking for every single day and verifying it is a weekday or a holiday I create a table which lists only the business days and then take the nth value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_n_working_days ( 
  start_date DATE, working_days PLS_INTEGER
) RETURN DATE AS
  l_end_date DATE := start_date;
  l_counter  pls_integer := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    business_day 
    INTO l_end_date
  FROM 
  (
    WITH 
    dates AS
      (SELECT start_date + level - 1  as dt FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 100)
    ,weekdates AS
    (SELECT dt as weekday FROM dates WHERE TO_CHAR(dt,'fmdy') NOT IN ('sat','sun'))
    ,business_days AS
    (
    SELECT weekday as business_day FROM weekdates
    MINUS
    SELECT holiday FROM so_holidays 
    )
    SELECT business_day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) as rn from business_days
  )
  WHERE rn = working_days + 1;
  RETURN l_end_date;
END add_n_working_days;
```

If working_days gets too high then I suggest making that value 100 a variable.

Comment: Did you post your answer to the wrong question? This answer doesn't seem to apply to the question.

Comment: Looks like it. And no one told me for over a year :)

Comment: on second review I do see that you are using `ROW_NUMBER`. Maybe you can call that out and how it applies to this question. I don't even think ORDER BY 1 works in MSSQL in OVER. I tried that first before coming here ;)

Comment: The other answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
a.City,
a.len
from
(
select city,length(city) AS len,
row_number()over(order by length(city) desc, city) as hi,
row_number()over(order by length(city), city) as lo
from
STATION) as a where (a.lo=1 or a.hi=1);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.