# ROW_NUMBER() without OVER in SQL - two approaches

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why the following code produces different results in my case:

```
select 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (select 1)) AS RowNumber_approach1
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by %%physloc%%) AS RowNumber_approach2
from dbo.tb
```

Reference (there are more approaches):
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/05/05/sql-server-generating-row-number-without-ordering-any-columns/

Although it sounds like dupe with:
[ROW_NUMBER() without over in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12914499/1903793)
But that question does not point out the difference between two approaches. Neither it provides an answer.

**Update following comments.** I would like to explain what I want to achieve. I load a file:

```
Bulk insert [dbo].[temp]
from 'C:\sql\CSV\MyFile.csv' 
with ( 
    fieldterminator =';'
    ,rowterminator='\n'
    ,FIRSTROW=2
    ,CODEPAGE ='ACP')
```

Now I would like to see the original order (the same as in a file). Is it possible without prior modification of the file?

Comment: We have no idea what "in my case" means.  In a test sample, I did not get different results.

Comment: You shouldn't use either of them if you care about anything other than that they generate an arbitrary sequential number. And in that case the first is clearly superior anyway as it avoids a sort.

Answer (score 1):

[`%%physloc%%`](http://sqlity.net/en/2451/physloc/) is an undocumented column that returns the physical location of the record.

Ordering by this will likely (but not always) yield a sequential result of the returned records without an `ORDER BY` specified.  Thus, when you use a `ROW_NUMBER()` over the `%%physloc%%` order, it will appear to be sequential.

But, ordering by `SELECT 1` will randomly assign a `ROW_NUMBER()` value amongst the resultset.

If you truly don't care what value is assigned to which record, both are fine.  But one thing to keep in mind is that ordering by `%%physloc%%` will actually order those values to determine the correct placement of the `ROW_NUMBER()` result.

Ordering by `SELECT 1` will not.

Comment: Probably more likely the opposite if the OP is running at read committed isolation level. The plan with the `(select 1)` will likely (but not guaranteed) be in key order of whatever index was scanned (assuming that there is such an index) and the ones where `%%physloc%%` differs are fragmented pages.

Comment: With all that said, this being undocumented means it would be a terrible idea to rely on it for any purpose that actually matters... if anyone can dream up a use-case where it would. I can't recall, but haven't there already been seismic shocks when MS have removed other 'useful' undocumented things in the past?

Answer (score 1):

@MartinSmith is correct you unless you are simply trying to add an arbitrary sequential number neither are of much use.  Although I can think of several reasons I would add an arbitrary number including:

- deleting duplicate entries through use of a cte......
- Adding a fake identity column to a temp table I am creating by `SELECT INTO` (yes I know may not be best practice but this would be for dirty one off analysis not production queries).

Anyway, I don't think you are guaranteed to always get the same results but should many times if NO `ORDER BY` statement exists on the query. Because %%physloc%% will return the records in order of physical location identifier (file location, page, and slot) http://sqlity.net/en/2451/physloc/. Indexes, Primary Keys, Joins and a bunch of other things will change SQL-servers optimization and therefore potentially the order of the results.

Performance wise you should see a gain by using `SELECT 1/ no OVER statement` because your query will not be dependent on more data.

Answer (score 1):

The undocumented `%%physloc%%` consists of three identifiers:  `fileid`, `pageid`, and `slotid`.

This location is a physical address.  When SQL Server reads a table, it is generally going to read the table in the "page order" -- the first page, then the second page, and so on.  You are, in essence, asking if the read order is guaranteed to be increasing in terms of physical addresses.

There is no reason to think that "page order" would be the same as the physical location.  Admittedly, this would often be true.  For instance, I would expect the two values to be the same for:

- Tables that fit in one page defined on a file group with only one file.
- Tables that are created all at once on a quiescent system (I think SQL Server will allocate new pages in order) defined on a file group with only one file.

However, intermediate processing can result in out-of-order pages, so could allocating pages from multiple files within a file group.  You are seeing the results of something like that.

Having said that, there is a major difference between `order by %%physloc%%` and `order by (select null)` (how I write this).  In the first case, SQL Server will do the sorting for the order by.  The second has (by experience but not documentation) thwarted the actual sort.